# How Do I Add and Remove Dynamic Audio Devices in Python Gstreamer

Tags: python, python-gstreamer

I am attempting to write a Gstreamer Python program that will control the Whole Home Audio system in my house. The basic premise is that I will have multiple different options for sources (Pandora, MP3, Google Music, etc.) and will be able to play them in different "Zones" throughout my house. I have gotten it to work for dynamically adding a zone to a currently playing pipeline, but when I attempt to remove a zone the audio stops playing in all zones. Here is the relevant code, I can post more if necessary:

Basic Setup:

```
def __init__(self, username, password, zones=[]):
    # initialize the player
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make('playbin2', 'pandora_player')
    fakesink = gst.element_factory_make('fakesink', 'fakesink')
    self.player.set_property('video-sink', fakesink)

    # enable progressive download (GST_PLAY_FLAG_DOWNLOAD)
    self.player.props.flags |= (1 << 7)

    # create bin
    teebin = gst.element_factory_make('bin', 'master')
    tee = gst.element_factory_make('tee', 'tee')
    teebin.add(tee)
    ghost_pad = gst.GhostPad('sink', tee.get_pad('sink'))
    teebin.add_pad(ghost_pad)

    # set bin as audio sink
    self.player.set_property('audio-sink', teebin)

    # set volume
    self.player.set_property('volume', 0.01)

    bus = self.player.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect('message', self.on_message)

    # make everything accessible
    self.tee = tee
    self.teebin = teebin


def add_zone(self, zone_id):
    # create out first audio output device
    zone_name = 'zone_{0}'.format(zone_id)
    device_name = 'mono{0}'.format(zone_id)
    bin_name = 'bin_{0}'.format(zone_id)
    queue_name = 'q_{0}'.format(zone_id)

    # wrap everything in a convenient zone object
    zone = gst.element_factory_make('bin', bin_name)

    # handle sending to the proper sound device
    zone_device = gst.element_factory_make('alsasink', zone_name)
    zone_device.set_property('device', device_name)

    # create a queue to handle asynchronous playback
    zone_queue = gst.element_factory_make('queue', queue_name)
    zone.add(zone_queue, zone_device)
    zone_queue.link(zone_device)

    # add sink into element
    zone_ghost = gst.GhostPad('sink', zone_queue.get_pad('sink'))
    zone.add_pad(zone_ghost)

    self.zones[zone_id] = zone

    self.teebin.add(zone)
    zone.sync_state_with_parent()
    self.tee.link(zone)

def remove_zone(self, zone_id):
    # get zone
    zone = self.zones[zone_id]

    # get src pad that is sending audio
    pad = zone.get_pad('sink').get_peer()

    # block src pad
    pad.set_blocked(True)

    # set zone state null
    zone.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)

    # unlink and remove zone
    self.tee.unlink(zone)
    self.teebin.remove(zone)

    # remove zone reference
    del self.zones[zone_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your entire pipeline goes into PAUSE.

Try to follow the steps of the documentation

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html

> We can't just unlink element2's sinkpad from element1's source pad
>   because that would leave element1's source pad unlinked and would
>   cause a streaming error in the pipeline when data is pushed on the
>   source pad. The technique is to block the dataflow from element1's
>   source pad before we change element2 by element4 and then resume
>   dataflow as shown in the following steps:
>
> Block element1's source pad with a blocking pad probe. When the pad
>   is blocked, the probe callback will be called.
>
> Inside the block callback nothing is flowing between element1 and
>   element2 and nothing will flow until unblocked.
>
> Unlink element1 and element2.
>
> Make sure data is flushed out of element2. Some elements might
>   internally keep some data, you need to make sure not to lose data by
>   forcing it out of element2. You can do this by pushing EOS into
>   element2, like this:
>
> Put an event probe on element2's source pad.
>
> Send EOS to element2's sinkpad. This makes sure the all the data
>   inside element2 is forced out.
>
> Wait for the EOS event to appear on element2's source pad. When the
>   EOS is received, drop it and remove the event probe.
>
> Unlink element2 and element3. You can now also remove element2 from
>   the pipeline and set the state to NULL.
>
> Add element4 to the pipeline, if not already added. Link element4 and
>   element3. Link element1 and element4.
>
> Make sure element4 is in the same state as the rest of the elements
>   in the pipeline. It should be at least in the PAUSED state before it
>   can receive buffers and events.
>
> Unblock element1's source pad probe. This will let new data into
>   element4 and continue streaming.
>
> The above algorithm works when the source pad is blocked, i.e. when
>   there is dataflow in the pipeline. If there is no dataflow, there is
>   also no point in changing the element (just yet) so this algorithm can
>   be used in the PAUSED state as well.

Comment: I found that explanation. Unfortunately, they are talking about replacing one element with another. I am simply attempting to remove the element altogether. So I block the src pad as is recommended in the article you posted, but then I remove it completely because I don't need in anymore.

Comment: Reconnecting element1 and element3 does not work? Another "trick" might be to insert a queue as a replacement